# How to setup Apache to run Laravel rooted from a subpath?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-routing, mod-alias

The     `DocumentRoot` of `example.com` is in `/var/www/html`.

Laravel is installed in `/var/www/example/public` and I can access it using `http://example.com/dashboard` but problem arises when I try to access other routes like as `http://example.com/dashboard/login` and is throwing `404 Not Found` error. And saying `The requested URL /var/www/example/public/index.php was not found on this server.` Can anyone please guide me?

The [.htaccess](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laravel/laravel/master/public/.htaccess) file in the public directory is untouched.

Here is the `000-default.conf`:

```
ServerName example.com
UseCanonicalName Off
<Directory /var/www/html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /dashboard /var/www/example/public
    <Directory /var/www/example/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
#dynamic subdomain provisioning
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example/public
    ServerName user.example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    <Directory /var/www/example/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve using the following in the `000-default.conf` file:

```
<Directory /var/www/example/public>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AcceptPathInfo on
    AllowOverride All
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

And had to change the laravel .htaccess in the following way:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /dashboard

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ dashboard/$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```